# computation of a limit and Stirling formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Let $m,p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c > 0$, I have to compute the following limit:

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} 2k(m+2k)\frac{e^{\frac{-m}{2k}}(m+2k)^{\frac{m}{2k}}}{(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}c^{\frac{m}{2k}}}.
$$
It would be nice to have some help to know if the substitution with the Stirling's formula i do in the following is correct.

I first write differently the limit:
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{e^{\frac{-m}{2}}(m+2k)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{c^{\frac{m}{2}}}\right)^\frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{2k(m+2k)}{(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}},
$$

and we have that:

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{e^{\frac{-m}{2}}(m+2k)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{c^{\frac{m}{2}}}\right)^\frac{1}{k} = 1.
$$

For the other term, we have:

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}}
$$

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{e^{\frac{1}{k}\ln(k!)}e^{\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)\right)}}.
$$

Now, using the Stirling formula $\Gamma(z + b) \sim \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-z}z^{z+b-1/2}$ (with $z >0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$) for the $k!$ and the $\Gamma\left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)$ terms in the above equation, i obtain that the last expression is equal to:

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{e^{\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k-1}(k+1)^{k+1/2}\right)}e^{\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k}(k)^{k+\frac{p-1}{2}}\right)}}
$$

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{e^{\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k} - \frac{k+1}{k} + \frac{k+1/2}{k}\ln(k+1)}e^{\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k} - \frac{k}{k} + \frac{k}{k}\ln(k)+ \frac{p-1}{2k}\ln(k)}}
$$

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{e^{\ln(k+1)
             \left(
             \frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k\ln(k+1)}
             -\frac{k+1}{k\ln(k+1)}
             + \frac{k+1/2}{k}
             \right)}
e^{\ln(k)\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k\ln(k)} - \frac{1}{\ln(k)} + 1 + \frac{p-1}{2k}\right)}}
$$

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{e^{\ln(k+1)
             \left(
             \frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k\ln(k+1)}
             -\frac{k+1}{k\ln(k+1)}
             + \frac{k+1/2}{k}
             \right)}
e^{\ln(k)\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k\ln(k)} - \frac{1}{\ln(k)} + 1 + \frac{p-1}{2k}\right)}}
$$

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{(k+1)e^{
             \left(
             \frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k\ln(k+1)}
             -\frac{k+1}{k\ln(k+1)}
             + \frac{1/2}{k}
             \right)}
ke^{\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)}{k\ln(k)} - \frac{1}{\ln(k)} + \frac{p-1}{2k}\right)}}
$$

$$
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2k(m+2k)}{k(k+1)} = 4.
$$

And so the final limit is just

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} 2k(m+2k)\frac{e^{\frac{-m}{2k}}(m+2k)^{\frac{m}{2k}}}{(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}c^{\frac{m}{2k}}}
=
1 \cdot 4 = 4.
$$

I am not sure anymore if it is a proper way to use the Stirling's formula. Can someone say if he agrees with what i did please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the computation of the limit with the $\Gamma$ functions.
The limit is equal to $4e$ not $4$:

$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left(
\frac{2k(m+2k)}
{(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}\Gamma\left(k + p/2\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}}
\right)
= 4e.
$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To simplify the problem, write
$$A=\frac {2 k e^{-\frac{m}{2 k}} (2 k+m)^{\frac{m}{2 k}+1} } {\Bigg[c^{\frac m2} \Gamma (k+1) \Gamma \left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right) \Bigg]^{\frac 1k} }$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(A)=\Bigg[\log(2)+\log(k)-\frac m{2k}+\left(\frac{m}{2 k}+1\right) \log (2 k+m)\Bigg]-$$
$$\frac 1 k\Bigg[\frac m 2 \log(c)+\log (\Gamma (k+1))+ \log \left(\Gamma \left(k+\frac{p}{2}\right)\right)\Bigg]$$

Use Stirling expansion twice and continue with Taylor series.

When finished, use
$$A=e^{\log(A)}$$